# ValueListenableBuilder builder method not called after updating Notifier value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update the notifier value from parent widget whereas ValueListenableBuilder is defined in a child widget but the builder is not calling after changing the value.

Here is the parent widget code in which I have declared two child widgets as `StatefulWidget`  and also declared a static object of `Notifier` class. I am calling the method `updateMenuItemList` from `secondChild()` widget like this  `HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.updateMenuItemList(currentCat!['items']);` to update the list of `firstChild()` widget :

```html
class HotKeysWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static HotKeysWidgetState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<HotKeysWidgetState>();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HotKeysWidgetState();
  }
}

class HotKeysWidgetState extends State<HotKeysWidget> {
static DealsNotifier appValueNotifier = DealsNotifier();

updateMenuItemList(List<Food> list) {
    appValueNotifier.updateMenuList(list);
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(child: Column(children: [
  firstChild(),
  secondChild(),
  ],
  ),
  );
  
}

}
```

Here is my Notifier class:

```html
class DealsNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<List<Food>> dealList = ValueNotifier([]);
  ValueNotifier<List<Food>> menuitemList = ValueNotifier([]);
  ValueNotifier<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> categoryList = ValueNotifier([]);

  void updateDealsList(List<Food> list) {
    dealList.value = list;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${dealList}');
  }

  void updateMenuList(List<Food> list) {
    menuitemList.value = list;
    print('PRICE CHANGE: ${menuitemList.value[2].price}');
    print('MENU ITEM LIST IN CLASS: ${menuitemList}');
  }

  void updateCategoryList(List<Map<String,dynamic>> catList) {
    categoryList.value = catList;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${categoryList}');
  }
  List<Food> getDealList() {
    return dealList.value;
  }

  List<Food> getMenuitemList() {
    return menuitemList.value;
  }

  List<Map<String,dynamic>> getCategoryList() {
    return categoryList.value;
  }
}
```

And this is the child widget named as  `firstChild()` in parent code. Here the ValueListenerBuilder is declared:

```html
class firstChild extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return firstChildState();
  }

}

class firstChildState extends State<firstChild> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: HotKeysWidgetState.appValueNotifier.menuitemList,
builder: (context, List<Food> value, widget)
{
   print('MENUITEM LIST UPDATED: ${value}');
   return HotkeysMenuItemsWidget(
   key: menuItemsKey,
   currentMenu:currentCat != null ? value : [],
   );
},
);

}
}
```

```html
class secondChild extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return secondChildState();
  }

}

class secondChildState extends State<secondChild> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
                    
                    onPressed: (){
                    HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.updateMenuItemList([]);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'UPDATE',
                      maxLines: 2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

}
}
```

Anyone help me with this issue please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you see your prints? `print('PRICE CHANGE: ${menuitemList.value[2].price}');
    print('MENU ITEM LIST IN CLASS: ${menuitemList}'); `  but you don't see the ` print('MENUITEM LIST UPDATED: ${value}');` , right ?  what if you hot reload, do you see the changes?

Comment: I suggest sharing more your full widget code and how you're calling `updateMenuItemList` because its still not clear how its being called and if you're using the same instance of `DealsNotifier`

Comment: Updated my post with some additional code snippets. I hope it will work out now.

Comment: Yes, I can see these prints, and after hot reload data changes in the UI. But that happens after hot reload, or if navigate to another menu and then comes back to previous. It is not updating the UI at that moment when the method ```updateMenuItemList``` is called

Answer (score 1):

While there's still not enough code shared to fully reproduce your situation, I can offer some suggestions.

The `state` portion of `StatefulWidgets` are private by default for a reason. You shouldn't make them public just to access variables that are inside there are several other to access outside classes within widgets.

So anytime you're doing something like this

```
class firstChild extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return firstChildState();
  }
}

class firstChildState extends State<firstChild> {
  @override
...
```

Just stick to the default syntax of a `StatefulWidget` and also classes should be in `UpperCamelCase` with the first letter capitalized.

```
class FirstChild extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstChild> createState() => _FirstChildState();
}

class _FirstChildState extends State<FirstChild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
```

If you find yourself wanting to edit this default syntax its a clue that you need to find a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do. If you're need to access a `function` that is declared in a `Widget` from outside that `Widget`, then that function should be declared somewhere else.

All that being said, unless you need `setState`, `initState` or another of the lifecycle functions, then you don't need a `StatefulWidget` to begin with. All those classes can be `Stateless`.

An easy way to make that `DealsNotifier` class globally accessible without a full on state management solution is to make it a `static` class.

```
class DealsNotifier {
  static ValueNotifier<List<Food>> dealList = ValueNotifier([]);
  static ValueNotifier<List<Food>> menuitemList = ValueNotifier([]);
  static ValueNotifier<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> categoryList =
      ValueNotifier([]);

  static void updateDealsList(List<Food> list) {
    dealList.value = list;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${dealList}');
  }

  static void updateMenuList(List<Food> list) {
    menuitemList.value = list;
    print('PRICE CHANGE: ${menuitemList.value[2].price}');
    print('MENU ITEM LIST IN CLASS: ${menuitemList}');
  }

  static void updateCategoryList(List<Map<String, dynamic>> catList) {
    categoryList.value = catList;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${categoryList}');
  }

  static List<Food> getDealList() {
    return dealList.value;
  }

  static List<Food> getMenuitemList() {
    return menuitemList.value;
  }

  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> getCategoryList() {
    return categoryList.value;
  }
}
```

Then when you need to pass in the `valueListenable` you access via `DealsNotifier.menuitemlist` and its always the same instance.

```
return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: DealsNotifier.menuitemList,
      builder: (context, List<Food> value, widget) {
        print('MENUITEM LIST UPDATED: ${value}');
        return HotkeysMenuItemsWidget(
          key: menuItemsKey,
          currentMenu: currentCat != null ? value : [],
        );
      },
    );
```

Here's the `Stateless` version of all those classes and wherever you need the UI update you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` and pass in `DealsNotifier.whicheverVariableYouWantToListenTo` in the `valueListenable`. Then call whichever relevant method from the `DealsNotifier` class ie. `DealsNotifier.updateMenuList([])`.

And you didn't share your `HotkeysMenuItemsWidget` but if that's where you're looking to see the change in the UI, then that is where the `ValueListenableBuilder` should be. Its currently too high up in the widget tree all it needs to do is re-render the list in that `Widget`, you don't need/want an entire re-build of the `HotkeysMenuItemsWidget` from a parent widget.

```
class FirstChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder( // this should be inside HotkeysMenuItemsWidget
      valueListenable: DealsNotifier.menuitemList,
      builder: (context, List<Food> value, widget) {
        print('MENUITEM LIST UPDATED: ${value}');
        return HotkeysMenuItemsWidget(
          key: menuItemsKey,
          currentMenu: currentCat != null ? value : [],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class SecondChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        DealsNotifier.updateMenuList([]); 
      },
      child: Text(
        'UPDATE',
        maxLines: 2,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HotKeysWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HotKeysWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FirstChild(),
          SecondChild(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my Notifier class as according to your code but it is giving same result as in my previous code. builder callback is not calling after changing notifier value. Kindly help me with some other way round.

Comment: I appreciate you for giving me the feedback on my code and these little suggestions.

Comment: Did you move the `ValueListenableBuilder` down to the `HotkeysMenuItemsWidget`?

Comment: I an unable move ```ValueListenableBuilder``` to ```HotkeysMenuItemsWidget``` widget because I have only shared a small piece of code of ```FirstChild ``` widget in which ```ValueListenableBuilder``` is being used. There are many other widgets and a whole logic for this single child widget. So I need this as separate widget..

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to move it down the widget tree. Try adding `HotkeysMenuItemsWidget` code or sharing a repo because I still can't duplicate everything you have going on to see what the issue is.